# Subsonic - Bit operation in Where Clause

Tags: subsonic, where-clause, bit

I'm trying to make something like this:

```
int count = new Select().From(tblSchema).Where("Type & 1").IsEqualTo("1").GetRecordCount();
```

And the error message is:

Incorrect syntax near '&'.

Must declare the scalar variable "@Deleted".

Is it possible to do that with SubSonic?

Comment: It isn't very clear what you are trying to accomplish could you add Write out the SQL statement that you want SubSonic to generate

Comment: i'm gonna guess select count(*) where type & 1

Answer (score 0):

> Must declare the scalar variable
>   "@Deleted"

The second error would be caused by using logical deletes on the table you are querying (the table has an isDeleted or Deleted column).

But I'm looking through the code, I'm not sure how that parameter is getting in there. The [SqlQuery.GetRecordCount](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#uMk-eK7JVdM/trunk/SubSonic/SqlQuery/SqlQuery.cs&q=GetRecordCount) method doesn't call CheckLogicalDelete(), from what I can tell. Is that error message unrelated?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in the way SubSonic is naming it's parameters when it generates the SQL to be executed.

What's happening is that SubSonic is looking at "Type & 1" and then creating a parameter to compare against called @Type&10 which is not a valid SQL parameter name. So you'll end up with the following SQL from your original query. You should submit a bug to http://code.google.com/p/subsonicproject/

Meanwhile you can workaround the bug for now by using an inline query:

http://subsonicproject.com/docs/Inline_Query_Tool

Answer (score -1):

It is a little fuzzy as to what you are trying to accomplish but here is a best guess.

```
int count = new Select().From(tbl.Schema).Where(tbl.TypeColumn).IsEqualTo(true).GetRecordCount();
```